# query getting killed in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm executing one select statement on Redshift, my table contain around 56 million records. The issue after executing for a minute the query is getting killed by the system.
On the command prompt message is showing as `Killed` and on the AWS console the status is `incomplete`.

Can anybody tells what can be the reason.

The cluster specification is below:

```
Current Node Type:  dw1.xlarge
CPU:                4.4 EC2 Compute Units (2 virtual cores) per node
Memory:             15 GiB per node
Storage:Disk        2TB HDD storage per node
I/O Performance:    Moderate
Platform:           64-bit
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: No, Im still facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi gmemon, have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: It turns out that the query was returning too many results and different clients (e.g., psql, jdbc clients) were not displaying the proper error message.

Comment: It could be because of statement timeout configuration or WLM 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_statement_timeout.html

Answer (score 0):

You've haven't given us enough info to help much. :( It sounds like your query has a problem that prevents it from completing. Please add more detail about the query and the tables being queried.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue (syntactically) with the query, as it was working with a smaller data, say table with 3 crore date.
 
What more details you will be requiring ti diagnose this?

Comment: You need to provide the query you're running. I suspect you have a cartesian product in the query. In that case it may be able to finish when the data set is small but as it gets larger the output increases exponentially, which exhausts Redshift's resources and causes it to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Is Workload management configured on the cluster? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm-c-defining-query-queues.html

If it's exactly 1 minute every time, it's possible you are running your query in a queue with a timeout

Comment: No its not 1 min every time, its varying.